# with or on a flexible schedule

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition is correct to use in this context: I want to say that by taking online courses, you can improve on/with a flexible schedule. Imagine it's a description of the course (one of the benefits): "Improve your skills with/on a flexible schedule".

Comment: "On" sounds better.

Comment: They are both grammatical, but they have different meanings. (1) *Improve your skills **by using** [with] a flexible schedule.* (2) *Improve your skills **according to** [on] a flexible schedule.*

Comment: Thank you for your help!